# variable as element of method call in a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the content from CKEDITOR for every div with the id change (change1, change2, ...)

```
var data2= CKEDITOR.instances.change1.getData();
for (var i = 2; i <= 30; i++){
if (typeof([\"CKEDITOR.instances.change\"+i]) != 'undefined') {
    var edit = CKEDITOR.instances.change[i].getData();
    data2 = data2 + '</div><div class=\"d W1 h1\">' + edit;
}}
```

I've tried it like this but getting error:TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.change is undefined at

```
var edit = CKEDITOR.instances.change[i].getData();
```

Comment: also tried: var edit = [\"CKEDITOR.instances.change\"+i].getData(); here i get the following error: TypeError: (intermediate value).getData is not a function at
var edit = ["CKEDITOR.instances.change"+i].getData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use typeof('...') because it will always return the typeof that object which is an object in you case, and then != from undefined...

try this:
    if (CKEDITOR.instances['change' + i]) {
        // put your code here
    }